# Show Inputbox on button click

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to optimize my Login/Registerscript and want to know how i can show 2 Inputboxes after a button was clicked.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhideLog() {
document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";
}
function unhideReg() {
document.getElementById('register').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
    <input type="button" value="Registrieren" onClick="unhideReg()" />
    <input type="input" value="test" name="userreg" id="register" style="display:none"  />
    <input type="password" value="Test" name="passreg" id="register" style="display:none" />
    <input type="submit" value="Registrieren" id="register" style="display:none"/>
</form>
```

I dont know if its possible when the Inputboxes all have the same ID. Also tried it already with different ID's but it doesnt worked also.
The problem is that the Inputboxes wont be shown after the Button was clicked.

Hope someone knows how to solve this.

Comment: Give id to form instead of all form's input. This is not a good way to have multiple component having same id in a single HTML page

Comment: Using the same ID for multiple elements on a page is illegal according to HTML standards. Most browsers will tolerate this, and (in my experience) have `document.getElementById()` return the first element with that ID in the markup. But don't rely on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML **IDs must be unique**, You are using `id="register"` multiple times thus your HTML is invalid.

Make IDs unique.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8BGT/1/)

*Is there no possibility to show all Inputboxes at once*

You can use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), Returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given class names.

[**DEMO with document.getElementsByClassName**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8BGT/2/)

*EDIT*

OP updated question

You need to use `()`.

Use `unhideReg()` instead of `unhideReg`

```
<input type="button" value="Registrieren" onClick="unhideReg()" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8BGT/)

Comment: Thats the problem. It works in examples like yours, but if i test it local it refuses to work.

Comment: After i changed the IDs it works now.
Is there no possibility to show all Inputboxes at once?

Comment: Got it now, i just copied it multiple times in the function.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique. For shared behavior you should use .class

Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oxfn/RH3bA/) of using classes to show couple of elements by .className

**HTML**:

```
<form action="register.php" method="POST">
    <input type="button" value="Registrieren" onclick="showControls('hiddenControl');" />
    <input type="input" class="hiddenControl" value="test" name="userreg" />
    <input type="password" class="hiddenControl" value="Test" name="passreg" />
    <input type="submit" class="hiddenControl" value="Registrieren" />
</form>
```

**CSS**:

```
.hiddenControl {display:none;}
```

**JS**:

```
function showControls(className) {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i++) {
        els[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```